# How do I collapse a result set in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have table

```
id name
1  nora
2  mars
3  ven
```

and I left join on id with this table,

```
id type     value
1  clothing shirt
1  clothing pants
1  toys     abacus
1  toys     legos
      ...
```

how do I produce something that looks like,

```
id name   clothing       toys
1  nora   shirt, pants   abacus, legos
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple join does not help if you want to put different values into different result columns.
You need to use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       (SELECT group_concat(value, ', ')
        FROM Table2
        WHERE id = Table1.id
          AND type = 'clothing'
       ) AS clothing,
       (SELECT group_concat(value, ', ')
        FROM Table2
        WHERE id = Table1.id
          AND type = 'toys'
       ) AS toys
FROM Table1
```